# Relationship between the infinity norm of estimation error and the trace of estimation error covariance matrix in Kalman filter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, dynamics, robotics, kalman-filters

I am working on designing an interconnected distributed control system. In this system, I need to use Kalman filter because the measurements are noisy.
I have two questions:

1 - What is the relationship between the infinity norm estimation error and the square root of trace of the estimation error covariance matrix in Kalman filter?
I have found a paper [that has an inequality relationship between the two mentioned terms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.12473.pdf). This relationship can be found on Page 4 below Equation 14. The relationship is:

$E(\|\mathbf{\hat{s}}(k)-\mathbf{s}(k)\|_{\infty})\leq\sqrt{tr(\Sigma(k))}$,

where $\mathbf{\hat{s}}(k)$ is the estimated state vector at time step $k$, $\mathbf{s}(k)$ is the actual state vector, and $\Sigma(k)$ is the estimation error covariance matrix. [The Kalman filter equations are taken from the original paper by Kalman.](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/fluidsengineering/article/82/1/35/397706/A-New-Approach-to-Linear-Filtering-and-Prediction)

I can not find a reference where this property of Kalman falter is mentioned. If anyone can introduce a reference for this property, I would be grateful.

2 -  I want to use the same idea to apply it to a distributed Kalman filter from paper I found with the title "Distributed Kalman Filtering for Interconnected Dynamic Systems". [The paper can be found in ieee Xplore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9457205). In this paper, they have found an upper bound for the trace of estimation error covariance matrix to show that the proposed distributed Kalman filter is asymptotically stable.

**My main question is if the inequality I mentioned in part 1 is a purely mathematical relationship between a variable and its covariance matrix or it is a property of Kalman filter.**

Thank you so much in advance!